# confusion on memory corruption c++

Tags: c++

```
class Test {
    int a ;
    int b ;

    public :
    Test() { }
    Test(int x , int y) : a(x),b(y) { }

    int getA() { return a ;}
    int getB() { return b ;}
};

int main () {
    list <Test *> mylist;
    Test *t1 = new Test(10,20);

    mylist.push_back(t1);
    delete t1 ;   //deleting the pointer

    list <Test*> ::iterator it ;

    for( it = mylist.begin() ; it != mylist.end() ; ++it ) {
        Test *temp = (*it) ;
        cout<<"taking data from list="<<temp->getB()<<endl;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

I am confuse about the output of the program , after inserting pointer in the list i deleted the pointer . Ideally it should give segmentation fault but it is printing 0 .

Comment: As mentioned above, accessing the freed memory pointed to by the Test* in your list yields undefined behavior and is not in any way guaranteed to result in a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete t1 ;   //deleting the pointer
```

This `delete`s *not* the pointer, but the object, *pointed by* this pointer.

As you `push_back` *pointer* in the `std::list`, only the pointer is copied, not the real object.

Two of the standard ways to deal with this are:

- if you *really* need to store pointers in the container, `delete` the object when you know, that the `list` will not be used anymore
- the most common way to avoid such problems is to have `list <Test>` instead of `list <Test*>`.

Answer (score 0):

When doing

```
delete t1 ;   //deleting the pointer
```

you're deleting the object that pointer points to, not the pointer itself (which is copied by value into the list).

Taking the pointer later is a perfectly valid operation

```
Test *temp = (*it) ;
```

what it is not valid is to use a pointer to deleted memory which results in **undefined behavior**

```
cout<<"taking data from list="<<temp->getB()<<endl;
```

That means you might get access violation or garbage values or even the old values depending on the way memory has been managed.

Comment: but  some time it leads to crash in big software . Can you explain when it will crash or when it will give wrong result ?

Comment: @AvinashKumar Only the compiler writers know that answer. As for the standard it is undefined and you should not count on it working in any predictable way.

Comment: It depends upon a million things (e.g. memory fragmentation, runtime decisions, etc..) and cannot be predicted.

Comment: On a typical modern operating system, your pointers are virtual addresses. You will get an arbitrary value if the virtual address maps to a valid, readable physical address. Otherwise, you will get a crash. You obviously shouldn't rely on any of this behavior, this is just an explanation of why you don't always get the same symptom when accessing invalid pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Calling delete t1, just calls the destructor for the object and frees the memory. 
The value of the pointer doesn't change. It is just the value of a memory address.

So you can still access the memory block pointed to by t1. But the behavior is undefined.

With a debug you might get invalid data. because some debug heap implementations fill the freed memory with a byte pattern. In a release program you might get the old values and the program seams to work correct.